# generating line numbers out of uncertain hash length

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have code similar to the following in a rails view. The length of the hash where the data's stored is variable depending on the page. I want to be able to number each row. I know I can get the length of the hash like this `<%= hash.postdata.length %>` What's the proper way to number each row as they are generated by the each method? Note, I might not end up using `<tr>`s and `<td>`s

```
<% hash.postdata.try(:each) do |key, value| %>
      <% if value.present? %>
       <tr>
       <td><%= has.post.user.name %></td><td><%= simple_format(key) %></td>
       </tr>             
       <% end %>   
 <%- end -%>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `each_with_index` instead, which will give you a zero-based index:

```
<% hash.postdata.try(:each_with_index) do |(key, value), index| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

So the first loop `index` will be 0, then 1, etc. So you can output it using something like `<%= index + 1 %>`.

Note that if you only want to count rows with a present `value`, your current code will probably result in skipped row numbers. Instead, it'd probably be best to filter the hash first and get rid of the `if` conditions:

```
<% hash.postdata.select{ |k,v| v.present? }.each_with_index do |(key, value), index| %>
```

Comment: Thanks, doing `<%= index + 1 %>` gave me `undefined method + for nil class`

Comment: Doesn't `each_with_index` on a `hash` just present two parameters to the block: hash element as an array [key => value] and the index? I don't think it gives 3 parameters to the block.

Comment: Try `|(key, value), index|` instead.

Comment: I tried it on Ruby 2.0 and it didn't work as `|key, value, index|`